# Use 4K monitor in HD resolution to get clearer text

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution, dpi, 4k-resolution

As I spend 90% of my time reading code and documentation and seeing the display quality of new tables and smartphones I realize that they are way above the text quality I see on my 23" HD monitor.

By reading about 4K monitor I realized that they might be used to render clearer text but ... I want to use them in HD resolution... so any text would be more crisp.

Basically I want to keep the size of text, icons, etc the same but have them with better quality.

Can this be achieved with a 4K monitor "forced" to work into a HD resolution?

Comment: Sure you can. Just go to display setting and change it. I bet you won't get what you expect (`so any text would be more crisp`) though.

Comment: @TomYan Why not?

Comment: If you drop a 4k monitor to HD, you will just get bigger, blurrier text, as every real pixel will be making up part of a larger 'multi-pixel' without the benefits of smoothing that the 4k could achieve at its native resolution using larger font sizes.

Comment: @Tetsujin So... font scaling is the answer to achieve that?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KNzER.png

Comment: @TomYan It would be nice to detail your comment in a full answer to understand what you did

Answer (score 1):

What is the OS you are using? Windows, Linux, macOS?

As I have just bought my first 4k monitor for my Macbook. Yes, for macOS it by default use 4 pixels to display as 1 pixel, so as a result by default it will yield 1920x1080 working space. If you want only 1920x1080 of working space, I suggest you buy just [24-inch 4k monitor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PC9HFNY) as 27-inch will result in Jumbo text and I don't think you will like that. (I don't)

BUT! .. beware though, 4k is not yet standard you might have some unexpected issue on application level like me. In my case, android studio lag so much on 4k when I type, especially if I don't use default 4-pixel to 1-pixel scaling, it will be unusable SLOW.